# Tomcat: How to redirect www sub-domain to the naked

Tags: tomcat

I am having some trouble with Tomcat server: What I am trying to so is redirect all requests starting with naked domain to the one starting with www.
Googling and using the guide of urlReWriteFilter gave me some goos examples for the opposite direction (From the naked domain to www):

```
<rule>
    <note>
        Moves all annoying www requests to the naked domain
    </note>
    <name>Domain Name Check</name>
    <condition name="host" operator="notequal">www.maternal-beauty.co.il</condition>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">http://www.maternal-beauty.co.il$1</to>
</rule>
```

The problem is that when I just removed the 'www'prefix, I got no redirection at all. Each address I requested just returned the corespomding page without any redirection.

```
<rule>
    <note>
        Moves all annoying www requests to the naked domain
    </note>
    <name>Domain Name Check</name>
    <condition name="host" operator="notequal">maternal-beauty.co.il</condition>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="permanent-redirect">http://maternal-beauty.co.il$1</to>
</rule>
```

Note that the only difference is that I removed the 'www'prefix from the condition element and from the to element.
I can't figure out what is the problem here.
If it matters, I am using Tomcat 7.0.34, and of course the org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter filter.

Thanks for your reply,

Guy

Answer (score 1):

This may be outside the box from what you're trying to do, but couldn't you handle this more easily with your domain name provider? Most that I've used allow you to set up A records and forward, in what they usually call a control panel or console. In your case, this would mean having an A record for the www. version of the domain (all the www. versions use the IP address given and display the www. domain name), and forwarding the "naked domain" to the www version.